# codeigniter unable to insert multiple row

Tags: database, codeigniter, rows

I had try to insert multiple column on Codeigniter (CI)

this is **my views** :

```
<?php echo form_open('index.php/testadddiscount');?>  
     $n = 1;
     foreach($disc as $exist) {
          echo "
            <input name=\"iddisc".$n."\" type=\"text\" value=\"".$iddisc."\" class=\"textbox\" />
            <input name=\"dname".$n."\" value=\"".$discount_name."\" type=\"text\"  />
                "; 
       $n++
            } // end foreach

  <input type="submit" value="send" />
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

this is **my models** :

```
function discount() {
$query = $this->db->get('discount');
$query = $query->result();

$n =1;

foreach($query as $rows) {
   $data[$n] = array(
   'iddiscount'=> $_POST['iddisc'.$n],
   'discountname' => $_POST['dname'.$n],
   'status' => 1
   );

 $this->db->insert('test',$data[$n]);
$n++;
  }
 return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

this is my **controller** :

```
function testadddiscount() {

   $this->test_model->discount();

}
```

This will show the value but unable to store data into database

please help me

Thanks

Comment: can you past your post value ?

Comment: make sure input value and database column type are same.and you are getting value for all your input fields like in all your text box.other wise if any of them are not set then it will give warning and not inserted.

Comment: it can for instance : if I post on : 'iddisc' the result still ca be display using 'echo'